# Display last login time

Tags: login, date-time

I am using this script to get the last time a user logged in

```
function get_last_login($user_id) {
    $last_login = get_user_meta($user_id, 'last_login', true);
    echo human_time_diff($last_login) . " " . __('ago');
    }
```

I am calling it in author.php with

`<p>Last login: <?php get_last_login($userdata->ID); ?></p>`

I am trying to output  like "last login X days ago" but I can't get it working.

$last_login output is

`2011-05-13 18:00:06`

but the final output I get is

`last login 15108 days ago`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you formatting the `mysql2date()` input string as `'Y-m-d H:i:s'`, as [specified in the Codex?](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/mysql2date)

Also, why not use this same format as `$date_format`?

EDIT:

1. What output do you get for `$last_login?`
2. The second argument in `human_time_diff()` is optional. Why not just omit it? That way, if you get valid output from `$last_login`, you should get valid output from `human_time_diff()`.

EDIT:

The `human_time_diff()` function expects a *UNIX timestamp* for its first argument. Try wrapping `$last_login` in `mktime()`, e.g.:

```
$last_login_unix = mktime( $last_login );

human_time_diff( $last_login_unix );
```

EDIT:

Might want to use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) instead of `mktime()`:

```
$last_login_unix = strtotime( $last_login );

human_time_diff( $last_login_unix );
```

Comment: You're right Chip. I pasted the code from an example I found. Now I'm trying to output with this code: 
`function get_last_login($user_id) {
    $last_login = get_user_meta($user_id, 'last_login', true);
    echo human_time_diff($last_login, current_time('timestamp')) . " " . __('ago');
` 
but is not outputting anything.

Comment: Can you edit your question, to add/update your code? (See answer edits, above.)

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: See edited answer. :)

Comment: (And one more edit.)

Comment: @Chip Bennett: Don’t stop. We’re watching you! :)

Comment: `if ( 'big-brother' == $toscho ) be_scared();` ? ;)

Comment: Yes! I was wondering why the output was funny (23 days instead of 1 hour), now using strtotime it's correct! Thanks Chip, I'm learning so much on stackexchange!

Comment: I figured we'd get there eventually. :) The honest truth (at least for me) is that I learn just as much by trying to answer questions.