# Save user login date

Tags: login, date-time

I want to save the last login date but it doesn't work properly. It saved the first time I logged but then when I logout and loggin it doesn't change the last login time. (Stay the same)

```
add_action ( 'wp_login', 'set_last_login' );

function set_last_login ( $login ) {
    $user = get_userdatabylogin ( $login );

    // Setting the last login of the user
    update_usermeta ( $user->ID, 'last_login', date ( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ) );
}
```

Comment: This question has been answered before [by me](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/100929/how-to-keep-track-of-user-logins/100930#100930) for one and [by Chip Bennett](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/17175/21376) for another, and I'd bet there are others.

Comment: @s_ha_dum It doesn't help at all. An alternative solution wasn't my request.

Comment: If I were to answer your question I would copy and paste almost _verbatim_, my answer from the other question. That isn't an "alternate" solution. It is functionally the same as what you are attempting, except of course that it works. It even uses the same hook.